# Updating 'Created By' field in SP2010 programatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-studio, custom-list, spfield

I'm trying to import data from an .xml file to a custom list in SP2010(created programmatically).

I'm able to create and update all fields except 'Created By' as it says that "Cannot update read only field".

Is there any way that I can update the "Created By" field? Only Programmatically

This is my XML code.

Note : I don't have user Id. I only have Display Name. I need  field from xml code to be updated in SP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>

<XMLExport DBName="local_Report DB">

<documentexport DOCID="DJHD7WJWA9APWPWO457C20004FE01A">

<Business>

<![CDATA[ Bank Subsidiary]]>

</Business>

<Company>

<![CDATA[ DMS Softies, India ]]>

</Company>

<Region />

<Author>

<![CDATA[ Dushyant M Sharma]]>

</Author>

</documentexport>

</XMLExport>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SPBuiltInFieldId.Author:

```
listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = new SPFieldUserValue(web, userId, userName);
listItem.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for your suggestion. But The problem is that I don't have any userId or userName. I only have Display Name that I'm exporting from Lotus Notes DB to XML file.

Comment: Then you are in trouble, how the heck would you make sure a display name is unique? ;)

Comment: At this moment I'm not considering uniqueness. I just want SP to somehow match that Display Name from Active Directory. If it is not present in Active Directory then it should update 'Created By' with "System Account".

Comment: Well, display name i AD is in no way unique, so you can not in a secure way identify a specific user from it.

Comment: Okay. I got your point Robert. But there must be some way by which I can do this.

Comment: What you would have to do is iterate over all User Profiles, check display name and if a match, use that Users SPUser.Id and SPUser.Name

Comment: It will take a long time in a big organization like mine where more than 250,000 employees work.

Comment: Yepp, that's why you use unique ID:s ;)

Comment: I think I was not able to make myself clear last time. I'll try to be more clear now regarding my question... :)

All employees have their unique IDs. But LN stores only display name after we enter user id. So when we export the data to XML file, it will export only Display Name.

So my target is to update that Display Name in Created By field of SP using XML file only. I know w/o userId it is not easy (and not the best way to approach) but still I'm trying to find some way.

Comment: Read all AD entries (account name + display name + first name + last name) to in-memory list, use that list to search potential duplicates from the import file, email duplicates to business side to resolve them (they need to take the responsibility of errors), and then import? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do:

```
SPFieldUserValue user = new SPFieldUserValue(Web, Web.CurrentUser.ID, Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);   

listItem["Author"] = user;
listItem["Editor"] = user;

listItem.Update(); 

web.Update();
```

`SPFieldUserValue` can be hard coded or as iv done getting the current user, `web` is the `SPWeb` object and `listItem` is the `SPListItem` object