# Update Editor (Modified by) for publising pages

Tags: splistitem, publishing-page, pages

I am trying to create about 1000 publishing pages using powershell. The powershell script reads data from a xml file. I have to update Modified By field for all newly created pages. 
I have used

```
$item["Editor"] = $user
$item[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Modified_x0020_By] = $user
```

and tested all following options for updating the item.

```
$item.Update()
$item.SystemUpdate($true)
$item.SystemUpdate($false)
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

but When I go to the pages list and, all pages is updated by user who executed the powershell.
**Updated: added Code**

```
$myWeb =  Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
$myPublishWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($myWeb)
$pagesListName = $myPublishWeb.PagesListName

$newFile = $myweb.GetFile("$pagesListName/temp.aspx")
if (-not($PersonaltidningspolicyFile.Exists)) 
{
  $myPage = $myPublishWeb.AddPublishingPage("temp.aspx", $myPageLayout)
  $myPage.Title = "Title Value"
  $myItem = $myPage.ListItem 


  $modifiedBy = $myWeb.EnsureUser("domain\testuser")
  $modifiedByUserFieldValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($myWeb, $modifiedBy.ID, $modifiedBy.Name)
  $pagesList = $myPublishWeb.PagesList

  $myItem["Title"] = "Title Value"

  $pagesList.EnableMinorVersions = $false
  $pagesList.Update()
  $myItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Modified_x0020_By] = $modifiedByUserFieldValue
  $myItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Editor] = $modifiedByUserFieldValue
  $myItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Modified] = $oldDate
  $myItem["Modified"] = $oldDate

  $myItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()          
  $pagesList.EnableMinorVersions = $true
  $pagesList.DraftVersionVisibility = [Microsoft.SharePoint.DraftVisibilityType]::Reader
  $myPublishWeb.Update()

  if($newFile.CheckOutStatus -ne [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile+SPCheckOutStatus]::None)
  {
        $newFile.CheckIn("From Powershell")
        $newFile.Publish("frrom Powershell")
  }
}
```

I have used UpdateOverwriteVersion and EnableMinorVersions to make it possible change the last modified date. I have even removed it and tested creating new page without that code and using systemUpdate(false) without success.

Everything works greate if I remove last part of the code (CheckIn and Publish) but I need to publish the newly created page.

Comment: You should create an SPFieldUserValue object and use it instead of the actual user object! The same approach, but a different field (works the same): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84232/updating-created-by-field-in-sp2010-programatically/84234#84234

Comment: I used it same problem.

Comment: Then I think we need to see more of your code, because something is done wrong!

Comment: I have added the code. It works when I remove CheckIn and Publish method, but the page is not published.

Comment: So the problem is not really with setting the fields, but to not get them overwritten on check-in and publish? Maybe you need to rephrase your question a bit to clarify that.

Comment: For that, take a look at the bottom of this script: http://sharepointvenividivici.typepad.com/sharepoint-customization/2011/06/maintain-file-version-history-when-movingcopying-files-between-sharepoint-sites.html

Comment: Thank you Robert I fixed it by moving CheckIn and Publish to the begining directly after creating the publishing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem seems to be related to the Publish of the file, try this approach:

```
 SPFile fileDest = libDest.RootFolder.Files.Add(
                 urlDestFile, 
                 streamFile, 
                 hashSourceProp, 
                 userCreatedBy, 
                 userModifiedBy, 
                 dateCreatedOn, 
                 dateModifiedOn, 
                 strVerComment, 
                 true);
     if (bolMajorVer)
/*Here we're checking if this is a major version and calling the publish method, passing in the check-in comments.  Oddly when the publish method is called the passed created and modified dates are displayed in the SharePoint UI properly without further adjustment.*/
          fileDest.Publish(strVerComment);
     else
     {
/*Setting the created and modified dates in the SPListItem which corrects the display in the SharePoint UI version history for the draft versions.*/
          SPListItem itmNewVersion = fileDest.Item;
          itmNewVersion["Created"] = dateCreatedOn;
          itmNewVersion["Modified"] = dateModifiedOn;
          itmNewVersion.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
     }
```

Source of this code: http://sharepointvenividivici.typepad.com/sharepoint-customization/2011/06/maintain-file-version-history-when-movingcopying-files-between-sharepoint-sites.html

Comment: I solved the problem by moving CheckIn and Publish to the begining of the code so I checkin first then I update the Item. thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2):

To create a SPUserField in PowerShell you can use

```
$user=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue(web, $userId, $userName) 
$item[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Editor] = $user
$item[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Modified_x0020_By] = $user
$item.SystemUpdate($false);
```

Comment: I used it but stil modified by for all pages is same and the person executes the script. I tested Author(created by) it changed but still editor is same.